# Matching substring within LDAP DN using Awk

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, ldap

I'm looking to parse the output of an LDAP query.  I want to retrieve a specific OU value within the DN that I am printing

```
dn: ObjectName=Value,ou=12,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
```

I am retrieving 3 total attributes values, but I only want the ou=[\d]{1,2} to be printed as part of the DN that I am printing.  Here is an example of my code that gives the full DN:

```
<LDAP SEARCH QUERY> | awk -F': ' '/dn: /{dn=$2}/^Attribute1: /{Attribute1=$2}/^Attribute2: /{print dn","Attribute1","$2}'
```

I'm not sure how to parse the ou=12 in the example.  I have tried several different but have not succeeded.  I would like to use Awk to do this as this will be ported to several systems and perl/python isn't an option in all cases.  I suppose it's like using grep -o but using Awk instead.

Here is the desired output:

```
12,Attribute1,Attribute2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
awk -F': ' '/^dn: /{split($2, ou, "," seps)}/^Attribute1/{Attribute1=$2}/^Attribute2/{print ou[2]","$2","Attribute1}'
```

The "ou=" is still there, but I am able to easily modify my script to accommodate.

```
ou=12,Attribute1,Attribute2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use only basic awk you can split the found `dn` variable value into parts separated by the string `",ou="` (assuming `ou=` is not first), then either look for a number (or take the second item of the split if you know that is always that field):

```
n = split(dn,x,",ou=")
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)if(x[i]+0==x[i])v = x[i]
# or just do:  v = x[2]
```

For your example input, you would get in array `x` at index 1, 2, and 3, the values:

```
ObjectName=Value
12
Users,dc=example,dc=com
```

We test for a number by adding `0` to the string. awk converts the string to a number (0 if it is not a number). If the result is the same as the original string, we have a simple number.

Alternatively, if you have gnu awk you can use `gensub` to match for the pattern and capture with `()` the number part, replacing the whole `dn` value with it:

```
v = gensub(".*,ou=([0-9]{1,2}),.*","\\1",1,dn)
```